# Определить битая таблица или нет

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго всем времени суток, господа.

repair table `table` - чудесная команда для восстановления таблицы, есть правда нюанс.. Вот работаете вы работаете, и раз.. таблица сдохла.. понятное дело надо восстановить.. но ведь не понятно когда она сдохнет.

Можно ли каким то образом настроить, что бы таблица перед любым запросам автоматом проверялась на "не_битость" и если она "битая" - восстановить автоматом.

P.s. конечно трайКэч можете посоветовать, но тогда как определить "битость" таблицы ?

Comment: Тиресный вопрос.

Comment: Да да! Вроде как даже сам боялся спросить..

Comment: Просто на практике не приходилось сталкиваться...

Comment: я что-то не понимаю? если таблица битая, то вернет код ошибки (в php), если код ошибки есть, то выполним восстановление таблицы, и опять пробуем тот запрос выполнить?

Comment: Мне на практике приходилось в 3ч ночи просыпаться, ручками Рэпайр.. и досыпаем до утра. Автоматизировать охота. Ведь MySQL как то определяет что есть повреждение, ну вот..

@IVsevolod - приведите пример кода

Comment: а что если с транзакцией данные добовлять и если она не прошла, то делать востоновление?

Comment: ммм... можно, но нужно как то не в слепую. в слепую - глупо. ведь не факт, что именно из за этого не прошла, хотя сейчас у меня именно так

Comment: @mixalef

    $result = mysqli_query( $link , $sql );
    if (!$result) {
        // что-то пошло не так, делаем предположение что таблица обрушилась
    }

а вообще, перед общим выполнением можно еще структуру таблиц проверить.

    SHOW TABLES [FROM db_name]; -  список таблиц в базе 
    SHOW COLUMNS FROM таблица [FROM db_name]; - список столбцов в таблице

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CHECK TABLE есть такой запрос:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/check-table.html

Нужно сверить Msg_type на error.

А такое будет в Msg_text: Table upgrade required. Please do "REPAIR TABLE `tbl_name`" to fix it

Comment: Если это делать перед тем как вставить данные, что как бы логично, и, вдруг таблица битая как определить на каком этапе она сломалась?

Comment: @vkovalchuk88 - оно самое! Жаль, что все на английском, убьюсь наверно с переводом, но вот такую проверку я и хотел